# Unable to find the Path of AudioFile using Google Music Uri

Tags: android

Hey friends i have a problem i use the following thing in my do in background to get the Path of the Audio file:

'   String[] proj = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION };
            Uri gMusicUri = Uri.parse("content://com.google.android.music.MusicContent/audio");//content://com.google.android.music.MusicContent/audio

```
        Log.d("onCreate(): XX gMusicUri = %s",""+ gMusicUri);
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(gMusicUri, proj, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            // query failed, handle error.
            Log.w("onCreate(): XX cursor is null"," query failed");
        } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            // no media on the device
            Log.w("onCreate(): XX cursor cannot move to 1st element"," no media on device");
        } else {
            int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);

            int titleColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int artistColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            int albumColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
            int durationColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
            int albumColumnId = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);

            int path = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
            do {
               long id = cursor.getLong(idColumn);
               String title = cursor.getString(titleColumn);
               String artist = cursor.getString(artistColumn);
               String album = cursor.getString(albumColumn);
               String albumID = cursor.getString(albumColumnId);
               String durID = cursor.getString(durationColumn);

               try {

                   String Path=getPath(context, gMusicUri);
                  // int idpath = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
                   Log.d("Id path is this", "=="+Path);
                  // String songPath = cursor.getString(idpath);
                  //Log.w("path"+titleColumn+","+artistColumn+","+albumColumn+","+durationColumn, "" +albumColumnId);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

               // ...process entry...
                Log.i("onCreate(): XX id = %d, title = %s, artist = %s",""+ id +  title + artist + "---" +album + albumID + "---"+durID);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.d("Error", "illegel");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }'
```

When i try to get the path it through some exception

Comment: A `Uri` is not necessarily a `File`: http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/04/uri-not-necessarily-file.html Use `openInputStream()` and `getType()` on a `ContentResolver` to work with the `Uri`.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column _data
 Sir i still got the same error

Comment: Sir as you mention above in your article we have tried this with the open stream and now we got the following error                     java.io.FileNotFoundException: /content:/com.google.android.music.MusicContent/audio: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)                       

And If we try with the Content resolver it gives the following exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column _data

Comment: Hey efroze i also got the same problem if you found any solution so kindly acknowledge me Thank you